# Google PubSub Bigquery Subscription fails if the topic schema has nullable field and in Biguquery it is Required field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

While creating a BigQuery Subscription, it fails if the Topic Schema has a field which is not explicitly defined as nullable but is Required field in Bigquery table. I cannot create new tables with the required fields as nullable.

The topic schema is using protocol buffer .I tried adding required in protobuf schema but it does not work for both protobuf version 2 and 3.

The protocol buffer schema used for topic validation

[image]

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SampleTableRecord{
    string Id = 1;
    string Field1 = 2;
}
```

The table schema
[image]

```
[
  {
    "name": "Id",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Field1",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  }
]
```

The error

```
Incompatible schema mode for field 'Id': field is NULLABLE in the topic schema, but REQUIRED in the BigQuery table schema.
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see both the topic schema and the BigQuery table schema.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please check now? @KamalAboul-Hosn

Answer (score -1):

A schema with a required field specified in proto2 should work. Proto3 does not support required fields, so that means it cannot be used with `REQUIRED` fields in the BigQuery table. I tested and the schema that worked for me was:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message SampleTableRecord{
    required string Id = 1;
    optional string Field1 = 2;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what do you mean? It worked exactly like this when I tested it. What is your BQ table schema and what is your Pub/Sub schema you are trying? What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I was using terraform and I think I was doing something wrong. It does work.